In which order should I watch "To Every You I've Loved Before" and "To Me, the One Who Loved You"?
I would like to watch To Every You I've Loved Before and To Me, the One Who Loved You, but I am not sure in which order I should watch them.
Can someone help me, please?

You can start with either one. There's no correct order for watching them.
I started with the longer one (I don't recall which one it is).
They say the story changes based on the order, but it didn't make much of a difference when I watched both movies a second time in the reverse order.
